# Getting only hours and minutes from date object

Tags: javascript

I want to get a `JavaScript` code that displays only hour, minute and AM or PM. I don't want seconds.

This is the code i have so far:

```
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
```

Answer (score 3):

`Date` objects have `getHours()` and `getMinutes()` methods.

`getHours()` returns values in the range of [0, 23], meaning you can compare with 12 to determine 'am' or 'pm'.

Lastly, consider using mdn as a helpful reference about the standard API.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours

```js
let d = new Date('December 17, 1995  22:11:51');
let pm = d.getHours() >= 12;
let hour12 = d.getHours() % 12;
if (!hour12) 
  hour12 += 12;
let minute = d.getMinutes();
console.log(`${hour12}:${minute} ${pm ? 'pm' : 'am'}`);
```